# I want to compare the rows in table and find mismatches

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

[image]

I want the query which can pull last three rows with all columns and with another column which specifies type of mismatch i.e. accounting, currency..etc.

Can any one help me with this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us your current query attempt, and the expected result?

Comment: please add DDL for the queries.Check here on how to ask:spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: SELECT gfd.ticker,gfd.segment,gfd.value1,gfd.value2,gfd.accounting,gfd.currency,gfd.multiplier
(CASE
WHEN gfd.ticker=gfd.ticker and gfd.segment=gfd.segment and gfd.value1=gfd.value1 and gfd.value2=gfd.value2 and gfd.accounting<>gfd.accounting and gfd.currency=gfd.currency and gfd.multiplier=gfd.multiplier THEN 'accounting_diff'
END) AS 'mismatch_type',gfd.user

FROM companies_financial_data gfd

WHERE gfd.date_of_update BETWEEN '06/07/2016' and '07/07/2016';

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you want but have a look at this

```
/*
drop table t
create table  T (ticker VARCHAR(1), accounting varchar(1), currency varchar(1), multiplier varchar(1), dte date)
truncate table t
INSERT INTO T VALUES
('a','p','u','m','2016-06-06'),
('a','p','u','m','2016-06-07'),
('b','g','c','m','2016-06-07'),
('c','p','u','b','2016-06-07')

*/

select u.ticker,u.accounting,u.currency,u.multiplier,
        concat(diff,',',diff2,',',diff3) as diffs        
from
(
select t.*,
        case when t.accounting <> t.a2 or t.accounting <> t.a3 then 'Accounting' else '' end as diff,
        case when t.currency <> t.c2 or t.currency <> t.c3 then 'Currency' else '' end as diff2,
        case when t.multiplier <> t.m2 or  t.multiplier <> t.m3  then 'Multiplier'  else '' end as diff3

from
(

select s.*,
        case when s.rn =  1 then lead(s.accounting, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY s.rn) 
            when s.rn =  2 then lag(s.accounting, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY s.rn)
            when s.rn =  3 then lag(s.accounting, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY s.rn)  
        end as a2,

        case when s.rn =  1 then lead(s.accounting, 2,0) OVER (ORDER BY s.rn) 
             when s.rn =  2 then lead(s.accounting, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY s.rn) 
             when s.rn =  3 then lag(s.accounting, 2,0) OVER (ORDER BY s.rn) 
        end as a3,

        case when s.rn =  1 then lead(s.currency, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY s.rn) 
            when s.rn =  2 then lag(s.currency, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY s.rn)
            when s.rn =  3 then lag(s.currency, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY s.rn)  
        end as c2,

        case when s.rn =  1 then lead(s.currency, 2,0) OVER (ORDER BY s.rn) 
             when s.rn =  2 then lead(s.currency, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY s.rn) 
             when s.rn =  3 then lag(s.currency, 2,0) OVER (ORDER BY s.rn) 
        end as c3,

        case when s.rn =  1 then lead(s.multiplier, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY s.rn) 
            when s.rn =  2 then lag(s.multiplier, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY s.rn)
            when s.rn =  3 then lag(s.multiplier, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY s.rn)  
        end as m2,

        case when s.rn =  1 then lead(s.multiplier, 2,0) OVER (ORDER BY s.rn) 
             when s.rn =  2 then lead(s.multiplier, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY s.rn) 
             when s.rn =  3 then lag(s.multiplier, 2,0) OVER (ORDER BY s.rn) 
        end as m3

from
(
select  top 3
        row_number() over (order by dte) rn,
        t.ticker,t.accounting,t.currency,t.multiplier
from    t
where   dte = (select max(dte) from t)
) s
--order by s.rn 
) t
) u
```